# Node JS : “Not a Constructor” Exception while creating objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, constructor, es6-modules, module.exports

I have defined a class like this (usage.js):

*Does not work*

```
  module.exports = class abc {
     constructor() {
    }}
```

**But if I export the below way it works**

*Working*

```
class abc {
constructor() {
}}

module.exports = abc;
```

**Usage of class in file calling.js**

```
const abc = require('./usage');
let abcinstance = new abc() -- Error - abc is not a contructor
```

What is wrong in the first way ?

Comment: You can try work with function insted of class. Its a nice clean way to create your code. Look: https://stackabuse.com/how-to-use-module-exports-in-node-js/

Comment: Any pointer what is wrong here ?

Comment: @SumitSrivastava There is no difference. It works fine for me. Also, when sharing code make sure that it compiles. Your first code has an unexpected '`' character at the end and your third code doesn't use double quotes for the require statement.

Comment: Thanks for the answer the answer, looks some issue in my project setup causing the issue.. I have edited the changes

Comment: Nothing is wrong, just a tip! (:

Comment: The code you posted works. Is this the complete code you're testing with? Try placing a debugger breakpoint at the line where the exception is thrown and inspect the actual value of `abc`. What is it?